# Parsing some XML and need to GET last in the array or latest date. Having trouble

Tags: xml, parsing

XML is here:
http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Datasets/ltcompositeindex.xml

But I am using a proxy on my server, cross-domain/same-origin is not an issue.

It's organized by "Quote Date" and I need to get the most current rate which is always last, I think.  Any idea for the best way to get it?  A timestamp won't work because today's date could be a weekend or holiday.  In this simplified example of the data I would only like to print,

"Date: 12-OCT-11, Rate: 2.87"

Thanks!

```
<G_QUOTE_DATE>
  <QUOTE_DATE>11-OCT-11</QUOTE_DATE>
  <RATE_TYPE>BC_20year</RATE_TYPE>
  <G_RATE>
    <RATE>1000.87</RATE>
  </G_RATE>
</G_QUOTE_DATE>
<G_QUOTE_DATE>
<QUOTE_DATE>12-OCT-11</QUOTE_DATE>
  <RATE_TYPE>BC_20year</RATE_TYPE>
  <G_RATE>
    <RATE>2.87</RATE>
  </G_RATE>
</G_QUOTE_DATE>
```

Comment: what are you using to parse it ?

Comment: i will parse with jQuery - $.ajax({
   url:'localData.xml',
   dataType: 'xml',
   type:'post',
   success: function(data){
   var f_xml = $(data);
   
   console.log(f_xml);

   }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Try an XPath like this:

```
//QUOTE_DATE[last()]/G_RATE/RATE
```